# Why is Symfony/Doctrine query giving me a different answer to debugged query with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

My deleted record is not being filtered out.

The doctrine querybuilder expression is:

```
  $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('duty')
    ->select(array('duty'))
    ->where('duty.validFrom < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AND (duty.deleted IS NULL OR duty.deleted > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())')
    ->orderBy('duty.rank', 'ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('duty.validFrom', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery();
```

I get 6 results (value of one has deleted as half an hour ago.

I grab a debugger and evaluate $q->getSQL(). It gives me:

```
SELECT e0_.id AS id_0, e0_.name AS name_1, e0_.rank AS rank_2, e0_.rate AS rate_3, e0_.validFrom AS validfrom_4, e0_.deleted AS deleted_5, e0_.created AS created_6, e0_.updated AS updated_7 
FROM employmentduty e0_ 
WHERE e0_.validFrom < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
AND (e0_.deleted IS NULL OR e0_.deleted > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
ORDER BY e0_.rank ASC, e0_.validFrom DESC
```

Which I run directly against postgres and get 5 results with the deleted item filtered out.

Comment: Sounds like a time zone mismatch.

Comment: Ah yes - in postgres. select CURRENT_TIME is an hour ago - so no daylight saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timezone for php is 'Australia/Sydney', the postgres timezone (`show timezone`) was set to `Etc/GMT-10`.

I set `timezone = 'Australia/Sydney'` in postgresql.conf so that the timezone matches the PHP setting. This application only has one timezone, so this is fine.

The date is of course set using `->setDeleted(new DateTime())` which uses the php concept of now, whereas the query is done with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which is the reason for the incongruence.